# Deleting comments of a certain blog post

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to delete all comments that are part of a certain blog post that is about to get deleted with mongoose. I don't really understand why my code isn't working.

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: { type: String, required: true },
  likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  parentBlog: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Blog"
  },
  commenter: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User"
  }
});

router.delete("/:title_url", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  const successMessage = "Successfully deleted blog post.";
  const errorMessage = "Error in deleting blog post.";
  Blog.findOne({ title_url: req.params.title_url })
    .then(foundBlog => {
      Comment.deleteMany({
        parentBlog: foundBlog._id
      });
      foundBlog.remove();
      console.log(foundBlog);
      return res.status(200).json({ message: successMessage });
    })
    .catch(res.status(500).json({ message: errorMessage }));
});
```

The console.log gets logged correctly, right before I get the following error:

```
(node:3108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Edit: Here's my final working solution.

```
// delete Blog Post route
router.delete("/:title_url", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  const successMessage = "Successfully deleted blog post.";
  const errorMessage = "Error in deleting blog post.";
  // delete Post
  Blog.findOneAndRemove({ title_url: req.params.title_url })
    .populate("comments")
    .then(async foundBlog => {
      // delete Comment references from Commenters
      await foundBlog.comments.forEach(async comment => {
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(comment.commenter._id, {
          $pull: { comments: comment._id }
        });
      });
      // delete Post reference from Post Author
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(foundBlog.author, {
        $pull: { blogs: foundBlog._id }
      });
      // delete all child Comments
      await Comment.deleteMany({
        parentBlog: foundBlog._id
      });
      return res.status(200).json({ message: successMessage });
    })
    .catch(() => res.status(500).json({ message: errorMessage }));
});
```

Comment: I solved it. I forgot to execute a function in the catch block. It should say: catch(() => res.status(500).json({ message: errorMessage }))

Answer (score 0):

you can try that -

```
router.delete("/:title_url", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const successMessage = "Successfully deleted blog post.";
    const errorMessage = "Error in deleting blog post.";
    try {
        let foundBlog = await Blog.findOne({ title_url: req.params.title_url });
        Comment.deleteMany({
            parentBlog: foundBlog._id
        });
        foundBlog.remove();
        console.log(foundBlog);
        res.status(200).json({ message: successMessage });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: errorMessage })
    }
});
```

Actually you aren't handling the promise rejection.
I think that way the code is clearer and more readable
Hope that it helps.

Comment: hey thx for your reply. did you mean i don't handle it even after my comment? how exactly is your code different to mine? for me it looks like it's just another syntax. also, isn't the "await" keyword only availible in an async function? why would it work in your solution / what part of the code makes this an async function?

Comment: Hey, this is the same code but a little difference - in my code im handling error catching from both functions findOne and deleteMany ( you only handle the error of find function) . In addition, i prefer to init all api's when the server is starting and use async function for each api

Comment: Well, you forgot the "async" keyword which confused me quite a bit. But no problem, I figured it out pretty quickly. I edit my post and share the final solution I came up with. Further improvements (how I shorten the code, best practices, better performance) are still welcome.